# Adding Signature Field to Form in C# using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I'm looking to adding a signature field in a PDF form using itextsharp using winforms
Below is the code i tried.

***EDITED***

```
var writer = new PdfWriter(outputPdfStream);
PdfFormField SigField = PdfFormField.CreateSignature(writer);
```

The following error is thrown when the second line is run:

```
Error   1   'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments
```

I'm still learning the ins and out's of iTextsharp. Any guidance is very appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: "Below is the code i was thinking about trying " - you mean you haven't actually tried this? Perhaps try first and then come back with any problems you might have.

Comment: I have tried it. I'm sorry for the confusion. I updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is telling you that there isn't a constructor for `iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter` that takes a single argument.

[How to sign a PDF using iText and iTextSharp](http://itextpdf.sourceforge.net/howtosign.html):

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
ks.load(new FileInputStream("my_private_key.pfx"), "my_password".toCharArray());
String alias = (String)ks.aliases().nextElement();
PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey)ks.getKey(alias, "my_password".toCharArray());
Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("original.pdf");

FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("signed.pdf");
PdfStamper stp = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, fout, '\0');

PdfSignatureAppearance sap = stp.getSignatureAppearance();
sap.setCrypto(key, chain, null, PdfSignatureAppearance.WINCER_SIGNED);
sap.setReason("I'm the author");
sap.setLocation("Lisbon");
// comment next line to have an invisible signature
sap.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200), 1, null);
stp.close();
```